# Lightswitch zapping me

Tags: electrical, light

This single lightswitch zaps every time it is touched. Including twice in a 30 second period when touched by different people. It is not the screws, but the switch itself. 
The zap is powerful enough that it goes through pliers with plastidipped handles.

Other things in the building are a little zappy; computers and whatnot. The outlets appear grounded.

Comment: when you say "the building" makes me think of a commercial property or something? If you don't own the place you should not go opening boxes or anything else. Report to management.

Comment: 120V won't go through plasti-dip, unless it's Cheese.  But "static electricity" sure will.  And it tends to be most active in the dryness of cold weather. Touch something *non-electrical* like a steel door frame or a doorknob, and if you get the same shock, it's static electricity. Disregard.   Otherwise it's considerably more than 120V and should be considered a lethal defect in your entire grounding system, fix ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely static electric discharge as Harper says.  The switch is grounded.  The computer case is grounded.  Walking around on carpet in the winter is a great way to build up a static charge.  When touching some metal at a lower charge a spark will occur.

The wall switch is at 120V in the US.  A static electric discharge can be 20,000V.

"... zaps every time it is touched"  Have one person touch it 10 times in 10 seconds.  Only the initial shock and nothing the other 9 times means it is static discharge.  A second person touches it and they got shocked the first time.
[image]